# How do I remove this part from url but still loading the pages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi recently I'm working on wordpress and need to change url like below,

https://abcd/portfolio/sample => https://abcd/sample

That without portfolio part and pls note that it is not a category and inside it there are portfolio groups and portfolio items.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example of what you have done

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your `.htaccess` file in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tags:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it's not the way I'm asking bro and it's not working I'll check this and it cause to error on server.